# Python 3.2: How to setup versioning for a project

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so I have been looking around and I have seen a couple different options although i am new to python so i am a bit confused. Here is what I am looking for:

I have a project of multiple .py files. I have my files and a lib directory for the libraries i have created. My question is, how do i setup the project to have a version? I see a lot of articles saying that I put the version in setup.py. Where does setup.py go? what else needs to be in that setup.py file? Do I just import setup.py into my python files? How can i check to see if it worked? How can i check the version of each .py file to make sure it imported correctly?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [hitchhiker's guide to packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project) to learn good practice for developing a Python project

> The setup.py file is at the heart of a Python project. It describes all of the metadata about your project. There a quite a few fields you can add to a project to give it a rich set of metadata describing the project. However, there are only three required fields: name, version, and packages. The name field must be unique if you wish to publish your package on the Python Package Index (PyPI). The version field keeps track of different releases of the project. The packages field describes where you’ve put the Python source code within your project.
>
> Our initial setup.py will also include information about the license and will re-use the README.txt file for the long_description field. This will look like:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='TowelStuff',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=['towelstuff',],
    license='Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike license',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
```

Comment: Ok, this works great. Thank you! however i do have a quick question. step 3: create your release, it says at the end to check that you have the correct version number. How? I am using cmd prompt in windows. Is the only way to check to see the number in the file name? is there a command that i can type to get the version number in cmd prompt?

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW from a command prompt you can do a `python setup.py -V` to get the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a project will include it's version as an `__version__` attribute within its top level namespace.

For example:

```
>>> import myproject
>>> print myproject.__version__
'3.2.0'
```

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/ for more info and ways to access `__version__` from within your `setup.py` file.